# Postponing the call of a destructor

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose, the program gets two arguments, one of them is `storage_duration_name` and the other is `count`. We have a class called `anywhere` which has a default constructor and destructor. The program must create exactly `<count>` (not more, not less) objects of type `anywhere`, one after another, starting from index argument value 0, and progressing up to and including `<count> - 1`.

The `storage_duration_name` can be Automatic, Dynamic, Static or Thread.

For example, if the command-line arguments are:

```
automatic 4
```

then the program must produce the following output:

```
constructor automatic 0
constructor automatic 1
constructor automatic 2
constructor automatic 3
destructor automatic 3
destructor automatic 2
destructor automatic 1
destructor automatic 0
```

The program has been solved for Dynamic.

For type Automatic, if I implement it with a `for` loop then each destructor is called after the constructor.  How can I "extend" the life of an object of this type?

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    anywhere obj(storage_duration_name, i);
}
```

Comment: Extend it to what lifetime? This is precisely what automatic lifetime is, what do you want to extend to?

Comment: I want to make object of 'anywhere' class for count times and then call their destructors.According to the problem they should have automatic lifetime.

Comment: You are already doing that. Unless you mean that you want to ensure that it creates `count` objects before destroying them in the same order. Which is something that you can't really do, as it involves *dynamic* data

Comment: Create them using recursion. Now all you have to do is figure out how to access them, at the bottom of the recursion stack, before it unwinds.

Comment: Thank you, and how about thread? Can I make multiple tread objects ?

Comment: I am not asking for a solution, I am just looking for some guidance.

Comment: @stdfile Objects in automatic storage are destroyed when they go out of scope. To control when they are destroyed, put them in dynamic storage. You can use `std::vector` to create the objects in dynamic storage, the `vector` itself will be in automatic storage. But this won't work if you need to pass different parameters to each object, like your example does. The `vector` would need to default-construct the objects, and then you can update them afterwards, eg: `std::vector<anywhere> objs(count); for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { objs[i] = anywhere(storage_duration_name, i); }`

Comment: @stdfile Otherwise, you can use `placement-new` to solve that construction problem, but then you have to allocate memory for the array manually, and call the destructors manually, which defeats the purpose of trying to use automatic storage at all.

Comment: `std::vector` and `emplace_back` should do. And call `pop_back` until it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, strictly speaking it is not possible to allocate an arbitrary number of objects of automatic storage class. Automatic variables are named objects, therefore one would need an arbitrary number of names, one for each variable. Furthermore, though the the C++ standard does not strictly require it, in stack based CPU architectures the compiler will allocate space in the stack frame for all automatic objects the parser recognizes in the body of a function. This space is allocated at compiler time, therefore function arguments cannot change the size of it.

There are several ways to implement a varying number pseudo-automatic variables. You can write a function template that passes the size of an array as a template argument. Then use placement new on an automatic array sized on the template argument, or use std::array to do the same thing. Instead of using a template argument, one can assume a maximum array size and forgo the template argument. Anytime placement new is used to construct objects in a automatic array, before the array goes out of scope the objects must be explicitly destructed.